# Replacing multiple values in a dataframe with `apply` method

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
    a   b   c
0   Out A   M
1   Out A   F
2   IN  no  F
3   Out no  F
4   Out no  F
... ... ... ...
751 IN  no  F
752 IN  no  F
753 IN  no  M
754 IN  no  F
755 Out A   M
```

I want to replace multiple values with other values using `df.apply()`. But it failed. Here is my approach

```
def replace_values(row):
    if row == "TOH":
        return "No"
    elif row == "n":
        return "No"
    elif row == "Out":
        return "No"
    elif row == "out":
        return "No"
    elif row == "OUT":
        return "No"
    elif row == "TIH":
        return "Yes"
    elif row == "m":
        return "Yes"
    elif row == "A":
        return "Yes"
    elif row == "IN":
        return "Yes"
    elif row == "M":
        return "Male"
    elif row == "F":
        return "Female"
    else:
        return np.nan
df = df.apply(replace_values)
```

Unfortunately, it gives me this error and I can't figure out what's going wrong

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `df.applymap(replace_values)`

Comment: Thanks @Chris but it returns almost empty df with a lot of NaNs

Comment: If you search with that error message there should be plenty of SO Q&A's to give you an idea of what to look for. Basiclly you are making a comparison on a container with many items - the result of the comparison can be True or False for any of those items **but** the conditional `if` is expecting a single True or False.  Put `print(row)` at the *top* of the function - is it what you expected?

Comment: @wwii yea I got this point but I don't know why a single cell could return False and True in the same case!!

Comment: @NemraKhalil Then you probably either have a different function or different data than you posted.

Comment: Values are replaced with a dictionary, not with a function

Comment: you can simply use something like this and then do the same for "yes" and Female/Male. `df = df.replace(['TOH','n','Out','out','OUT'], 'No')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `apply`? You can `replace` multiple values in a list with one value. You can also replace multiple values in a list with multiple values (if the lists are equal lengths as in the third replace:

```
df = (df.replace(['TOH','n','Out','out','OUT','no'], 'No')
        .replace(['TIH','m','A','IN'], 'Yes')
        .replace(['M','F'], ['Male', 'Female']))
df
Out[1]: 
       a    b       c
0     No  Yes    Male
1     No  Yes  Female
2    Yes   No  Female
3     No   No  Female
4     No   No  Female
 ...  ...     ...
751  Yes   No  Female
752  Yes   No  Female
753  Yes   No    Male
754  Yes   No  Female
755   No  Yes    Male
```

Answer (score 1):

1. When you apply your function without *axis* parameter,
   this function is applied to each **column**.

   In this case the parameter passed to this function is
   a **column**, not *row*.
2. Only when you apply your function with *axis=1* parameter,
   then this function is applied to each **row**.

   But then the comparison in your function shoud be made
   to values of particular column in this row (e.g. *row.a == ...*).
   And the returned value should be also a **row**, with respectively
   changed values.
3. But from your function I see that the object to compare
   is actually a **single cell** from **any column** and the returned
   value should be the new value for the current cell, as you wrote
   in your function.

   So probably, instead of *apply*, you should run:

   ```
   df.applymap(replace_values)
   ```

   Consider also the following changes in your function:

   - replace *row* with *cell* (everywhere),
   - if no condition has been met, probably the returned value
     should be just the parameter passed (*cell*).